# linq query to select top 10 entries with most comments from the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables "POSTS" and "COMMENTS". One post can have many comments and I want to be able to select the top 10 posts with highest number of comments. The post_id is a FK in the comments table. I am using Linq to SQL. Please advise me on how to do this . Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
var top = (from q in db.question_tables
                   from a in db.answer_tables
                   where q.QUEST_ID.Equals(a.ANS_QUEST_ID)
                   orderby q.QUEST_TEXT.Count() descending
                   select new
                   {
                       QUEST_TEXT = q.QUEST_TEXT


                   }).Take(10);
```

this is how my linq query looks like now , its giving an error "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'. " . :/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

That error message is because you are calling `.Count()` on a string property (`QUEST_TEXT`).  That compiles because strings are enumerable.  However, Linq-to-SQL doesn't understand this.

If you have the relationship between the two tables mapped in your DBML file, then you can use it in your expression:

```
var top = (from q in db.question_tables
           orderby q.answers.Count() descending
           select q).Take(10);
```

However the code you posted doesn't quite match the description you gave.  You mention comments, but the code talks about answers.

Comment: get the top 10 questions with most answers !

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz, I changed the code to show `answers` instead of `comments`, but that really depends upon how your DBML is set up.  Are you modelling the relationship between these tables?  If so, find out what the relationship is called and use that.

Answer (score 4):

Join `Posts` and `Comments`, order by `Post.Comment` count descending and the take the top 10.

```
(from p in Posts
from c in Comments
where c.PostId == p.Id
orderby p.Comments.Count() descending
select p).Take(10);
```

### EDIT

From your edits, it looks like you are trying to find the question with the longest QUEST_TEXT value. If that is what you need, just change your code to `orderby q.QUEST_TEXT.Length descending`, but that doesn't sound like what you originally asked.

Comment: What does the `from c in Comments where c.PostId == p.Id` do?

Comment: @Magnus, that joins the Comments table to the Posts table. The ID property names may be different in your case and can just be adjusted to whatever you have defined them as.

Comment: @scottm , i tried this but it gives me an error as "Sequence operators not supported for type 'System.String'." ...I have updated the question to show my query now..

Comment: Don't you mean `Count()` instead of `Count`?

Comment: @scottm that'll be done automatically if you use property `p.Comments`  as you have.